# Impossibility of Equation

Tags: diophantine-equations, square-numbers

Prove that there are no solutions to $ k^2 = x^4 + 2x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x + 1 $  in $ \mathbb Z^+$.

I have tried a bounding argument so far, placing $k^2$ in between $x^4$ and $(x+1)^4$, but I am unable to prove that this implies there are no solutions.

Comment: Oops, I have made an error, I shall correct the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$x^4+2x^3+2x^2+2x+1 = (x^2+1)^2 + 2x(x^2+1) = (x^2+1)(x+1)^2.$$

Comment: Therefore, we can conclude that $(x^2 + 1)$ is a perfect square. However, this never holds for positive integers as the gap between perfect squares is 2x+1. Thanks